# Is it self plagiarism if I use the same source for two different projects?

Tags: self-plagiarism

I found previous tuition and fees for other school years through reports that my university has published onto it website.

I am using these reports for two of my projects that I am turning into my professors next week that counts as a final exam for two different courses taught by two different professor.

Is it self plagiarism to use the same source such as a report showing tuition and fees from prior school year for two different projects that serve a different purpose and also intended audience?

Answer (score 1):

While the [answer of Snijdefrey](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/184796/75368) is correct, let me add a warning. What is plagiarism or self plagiarism in the real world is often immaterial in the context of coursework.

If two professors discover and decide that you are essentially using the same paper for two different courses without prior permission then you will probably be punished regardless of the wider meanings of things.

You are protected in the real world from charges of self plagiarism if you cite earlier work of your own, but professors might consider some things improper in an educational context even then.

I recommend that you seek permission from both professors and explain what you are doing. If they agree that the "two" papers are sufficiently different then you should be fine.

It isn't however, that you rely on the same source data for the papers, but rather the questions you ask and answer about them and what you say. Just be cautious and protect yourself.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "It isn't however, that you rely on the same source data for the papers, but rather the questions you ask and answer about them and what you say. Just be cautious and protect yourself". Are you saying that it not self plagiarism if using the same source more than once for two different paper that have a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not self plagiarism to use a source more than once. However, it depends on the extent of text and thoughts that come with the reference. If you recycle to much of that, it might become a problem. But there is one safe way to avoid charges of self plagiarism: Cross-referencing and thus making the aspects the two texts have in common transparent. Something along the lines of...

> [...] as also discussed in Text B [citation] [...]